# How do you get the entire page height from a webpage in Mobile Safari via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone

I need to get the height of the entire document in Mobile Safari for a particular webpage.  The entire page height, even if, you are zoomed in on a particular area of a webpage.

How is this done via Javascript ( not jQuery ).?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to do that:

```
function getDocumentHeight() {
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

Comment: why do you make 3 redundant Math.max calls?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Mobile Safari --- for a document that should have a height of ~900 pixels, this function returns 358px.

Comment: Edit: this function DOES work. In my haste to test, I had placed the call higher up in the DOM, before it had finished rendering. Thanks! :)